# Google+ sign in shows 3 times at log in

Tags: android, google-plus, google-signin

I have a weird problem when using Google+ to sign in my application, I receive the following three dialogs when I using Google+ in the next order:

[image]

then:

[image]

and finally the screen that combines the two previous ones:

[image]

In the end it works, but I guess it will be very frustrating for the user to use this option. Have some encountered this issue and know why this happening or how to fix it?

Here is my code:

**LoginActivity:**

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.google_login_button) 
    {
        auth = Login.instance.getAuthenticationType();
        Login.instance.setUpAuthentication(this, Google.class.getName(), new ConnectCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onConnected(String token) {
                finishActivity();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDisconnected() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

        });
    }
}
```

**Login** object:

```
public class Login {

private static final String TAG = Login.class.getSimpleName();
public static Login instance = new Login();
public static int startLoginCounter = 0;
private Authentication auth;
public FragmentActivity context;
private ConnectCallback callback = new ConnectCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnected(String token) {
        CupsLog.i(TAG, "Logged in with token: " + token);
        if (auth.getAuthType().equalsIgnoreCase(Google.class.getName())) {
            CupsTracker.instance.sendAnalyticsEvent(CupsTracker.LOGIN, CupsTracker.GOOGLE_LOGIN, CupsTracker.GOOGLE_LOGIN, null);
            CupsTracker.instance.trackMobileAppTrackerAction(CupsTracker.GOOGLE_LOGIN);
        }
        if (auth.getAuthType().equalsIgnoreCase(Facebook.class.getName())) {
            CupsTracker.instance.sendAnalyticsEvent(CupsTracker.LOGIN, CupsTracker.FACEBOOK_LOGIN, CupsTracker.FACEBOOK_LOGIN, null);
            CupsTracker.instance.sendAnalyticsView("fb login");
            CupsTracker.instance.trackMobileAppTrackerAction(CupsTracker.FACEBOOK_LOGIN);
        }
        AccountService.instance.pullAccountDetailsFromServer();
        WebFragment webFragment = (WebFragment) context.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.venue_fragment);
        webFragment.loadUrlInvisible(Consts.venueUri("C001"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        CupsLog.i(TAG, "Logged out");
        CookieUtil.instance.removeAllCookies();
        FileAccessUtil.instance.removeParameter(Consts.AUTH_TYPE);
        auth = null;
        startLoginCounter++;
        CupsLog.i(TAG, "startLoginCounter: " + startLoginCounter);
        if (startLoginCounter < 2)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
};

public void login(FragmentActivity context) {
    this.context = context;
    auth = getAuthenticationType();

    if (auth == null) { 
        Session.Builder builder = new Session.Builder(context);
        Session session = builder.build();
        if (session.getState().equals(SessionState.CREATED_TOKEN_LOADED)) { // if the user had a facebook session then keep him logged in with facebook for backwards compatibility 
            if (!FileAccessUtil.instance.isEqualString(Consts.AUTH_TYPE, Facebook.class.getName())) {
                FileAccessUtil.instance.setStringProperty(Consts.AUTH_TYPE, Facebook.class.getName());
            }
            auth = getAuthenticationType();
            Facebook.instance.login(context, callback);
        } else {
            // call login activity if this is a new user
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    } else {
        auth.login(context, callback);
    }
}

public void logout(Activity context) {
    if (auth != null) {
        AccountService.instance.setAccount(null);
        auth.logout(context, callback);
    }
}

public void setUpAuthentication(Activity loginActivity, String type, ConnectCallback callback) {
    if (type.equals(Google.class.getName())) {
        auth = Google.instance;
    } else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(Facebook.class.getName())) {
        auth = Facebook.instance;
    }

    auth.onCreate(context);
    auth.setLoginActivity(loginActivity);
    auth.login(context, callback);
}

public Authentication getAuthenticationType() {
    String type = FileAccessUtil.instance.getStringProperty(Consts.AUTH_TYPE);
    if (type != null) {
        if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(Google.class.getName()))
            return Google.instance;
        else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase(Facebook.class.getName()))
            return Facebook.instance;
        else
            return null;
    }
    return null;
}


public interface ConnectCallback {
    public void onConnected(String token);

    public void onDisconnected();
}
}
```

And the **Google** object:

```
public class Google implements ConnectionCallbacks, Authentication, OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = Google.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR = 9000;
private static final int REQUSET_TOKEN_PERMISSIONS_RESLOVE_ERR = 9001;

public static final Google instance = new Google();
private PlusClient mPlusClient;
private Activity loginActivity;
private String authToken;
private ConnectCallback connectCallback;
private String visiblaeActivities = "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity";

// A flag to stop multiple dialogues appearing for the user.
private boolean mResolveOnFail;

@Override
public void onCreate(Activity context) {
    mPlusClient = new PlusClient.Builder(context, this, this).setActions(visiblaeActivities).build();
    mResolveOnFail = false;
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle result) {
    mResolveOnFail = false;
    fetchAuthToken();
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    authToken = null;
    if (connectCallback != null) {
        connectCallback.onDisconnected();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    //The user clicked the sign-in button already. Start to resolve
    // connection errors. Wait until onConnected() to dismiss the
    // connection dialog.
    if (result.hasResolution()) {
        if (mResolveOnFail) {
            try {
                if (loginActivity != null) { 
                    mResolveOnFail = false;
                    result.startResolutionForResult(loginActivity, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR);
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.instance.context, LoginActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    Login.instance.context.startActivity(intent);
                }
                } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                    mPlusClient.connect();
                }
        }
    }
}

public PlusClient getPlusClient() {
    return this.mPlusClient;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent data) {
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLVE_ERR && responseCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
         mResolveOnFail = true;   
         //mConnectionResult = null;
         mPlusClient.connect();
     }
     if (requestCode == REQUSET_TOKEN_PERMISSIONS_RESLOVE_ERR && responseCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
         if (isConnected()) 
             fetchAuthToken();
     }
}

@Override
public boolean isConnected() {
    if (getPlusClient() != null) {
        return getPlusClient().isConnected();
    } else return false;
}

@Override
public String getAuthToken() {
    return authToken;
}

private void setTokenCookie() {
    String val = "google+" + getAuthToken();
    CupsLog.i(TAG, "Google access_token: " + val);
    CookieUtil.instance.setCookie("auth", val, true);
}

@Override
public String getAuthType() {
    return Google.class.getName();
}

@Override
public void login(Activity context, ConnectCallback callback) {
    this.connectCallback = callback;
    if (mPlusClient == null) {
        onCreate(context);
    }
    mResolveOnFail = true;
    mPlusClient.connect();

}

@Override
public void logout(Activity context, final ConnectCallback callback) {
    if (getPlusClient() != null && mPlusClient.isConnected()) {
        mPlusClient.clearDefaultAccount();
        GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken(context, getAuthToken());
        mPlusClient.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(new OnAccessRevokedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAccessRevoked(ConnectionResult arg0) {
                callback.onDisconnected();
            }
        });
    }
}

private void fetchAuthToken() {
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String token = null;
            String scope = "oauth2: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";//"oauth2: "+ Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE;
            Bundle appActivities = new Bundle();
            appActivities.putString(GoogleAuthUtil.KEY_REQUEST_VISIBLE_ACTIVITIES, visiblaeActivities);
            try {
                // We can retrieve the token to check via tokeninfo or to pass to a service-side application.
                int isGooglePlayServiceAvilable = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Login.instance.context);
                if (isGooglePlayServiceAvilable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
                {
                    token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Login.instance.context, mPlusClient.getAccountName(), scope, appActivities);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isGooglePlayServiceAvilable, loginActivity, 12).show();
                }
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                // This error is recoverable, so we could fix this
                // by displaying the intent to the user.

                Intent intent = e != null ? e.getIntent() : null; //fixes two crashlytics bugs
                if (intent != null) {
                    if (loginActivity != null) loginActivity.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUSET_TOKEN_PERMISSIONS_RESLOVE_ERR);
                    else Login.instance.context.startActivityForResult(intent, REQUSET_TOKEN_PERMISSIONS_RESLOVE_ERR);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return token;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            authToken = result;
            setTokenCookie();
            if (authToken != null) {
                if (connectCallback != null) {
                    connectCallback.onConnected(authToken);
                } 
            }
        }
    };
    task.execute((Void) null);
}   
}
```

Comment: Can u post ur code here?

Comment: @yahska, updated with code.